# Im trying to write a program with the quadratic formula in it and i can not figure out why i keep getting an error

Tags: python

```
import math
a=float(input("Enter value for a:"))
b=float(input("Enter value for b:"))
c=float(input("Enter value for c:"))
root1=-b+math.sqrt (b**2-4*a*c)/(2*a)
root2=-b-math.sqrt (b**2-4*a*c)/(2*a) 
print(("root1 % 8.2f")%(root1))
print(("root1 % 8.2f")%(root2
```

import math is the correct way to start my program right ? I keep getting an math domain error in line five? what is missing ? thanks

Comment: @GrishaLevit - Why?

Comment: @GrishaLevit That is a style problem, not a syntax error, not a run-time error

Comment: You also fail to close two brackets `)`...

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thanks, spaced on the language..

Comment: ["spaced"...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JCdCLgZrBI)

Answer (score 2):

`math.sqrt` only works for non-negative values. Either verify that `b**2 - 4*a*c >= 0` before calling `math.sqrt`, or use `cmath.sqrt` instead to handle complex roots.

```
>>> math.sqrt(-4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
>>> cmath.sqrt(-4)
2j
```

Note that if you use `cmath.sqrt`, printing the value becomes a little more complicated, since there is no format specifier for complex values; you need to extract the real and imaginary parts (`root1.real` and `root1.imag`) and format them separately.

Comment: `format(1+2j, 'e')` seems to work with e, f, and g.

Comment: Thanks; I put off checking if/how `format` dealt with complex numbers, and forgot to get back to it.